# WP7 WebBrowser control doesn't show scroll bars

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I'm using a WebBrowser control to show some dynamic content from a web service. I've noticed that the WebBrowser in the app doesn't have scroll bars so the user doesn't know how much they have scrolled relative to the length of the page. My xaml for this control is very basic, I'm not doing anything to it. I've noticed that IE on the phone does show scroll bars. Does this control not support scroll bars?

```
<browser:WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the WP7 `WebBrowser` control does not provide scrollbars. I can see that there are good reasons why this might be useful, so you should probably raise a feature request/bug report on the [App Hub](http://create.msdn.com).

Comment: Thanks, that sucks. Is there documentation on this from Microsoft.

Comment: None that I know of; it's just experience :)